# Cauchy iid random variables and Strong Law of Large Numbers (helping understand)

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions, probability-limit-theorems, independence

Question:

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Cauchy random variables with density $\frac{1}{ π(1+x^2)}$.
Use the characteristic function $φ(t) = e^{−|t|}$ of the Cauchy distribution to find the distribution of the average $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$$

How do the averages behave as n → ∞? Why does not this violate the Strong
Law of Large Numbers?

Answer

The characteristic function of the average is $φ(t/n)^n = e^{−|t|}$, that is, the same as for the Cauchy distribution. Hence each average is a Cauchy random variable. In particular, this implies that they converge weakly to a Cauchy random variable. This does not violate the Strong Law of Large Numbers since $E|X_n| = ∞$

---

I only understand the last part why it doesn't violate the strong law of large numbers but could any kind soul actually explain the answer to me? I dont even understand the characteristic function's average is $φ(t/n)^n = e^{−|t|}$ part. A detailed explanation would be sooo helpful as my exam is tomorrow. Thank you so much !

Comment: "I dont even understand the characteristic function has average..." $\ne$ "The characteristic function of the average is..."

Comment: @Did Changed.. would you mind helping below? thanks

Comment: Note that "the characteristic function's average" is still absurd.

Answer (score 3):

The general property of characteristic functions that you need follows from properties of exponents and independence:

$$E[e^{it \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}}]=E[e^{it/n X_1} e^{it/n X_2} \cdots e^{it/n X_n}] = E[e^{it/n X_1}] \cdots E[e^{it/n X_n}] = \phi(t/n)^n$$

where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of each of the $X_i$. Now you just need to check that $\phi(t/n)^n = \phi(t)$ if $\phi$ is the characteristic function of a Cauchy variable.

Comment: thanks ! and last question, why does $ϕ(\frac{t}{n})^n=e^{|t|}$ ?

Comment: @YauKinHoe That's just algebra, once you know that $\phi(t)=e^{-|t|}$.

Comment: would appreciate a detailed explanation, would upvote everything ! i get $ϕ(t)=E[e^{itX}]=e^{|t|}$? that true? then? :/ sorry

Comment: @YauKinHoe There should be a minus sign in there.

Comment: ohh why?? pls do it in detail thanks !